# Rails jsonb get all data with specific key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb

How can i get all value in that jsonb?

```
item = [{"name"=>"Name 1", "value"=>"Value 1"}, {"name"=>"Name 2", "value"=>"Value 2"}]
```

Update:
Is there a way to do it without json.parse? I thought it should work without it.

```
<%= data = JSON.parse(item.to_json)%>

<%= p data.collect { |item| item['value'] }
```

Comment: It the item variable the jsonb value? There is also a typo in the first jsonb: you're missing the closing bracket. It's not needed to parse. It's an array so you should be able to bet the value with `item[0]['value']` and item[1]['value']

Answer (score 0):

First, the first coding block you posted is not a JSON in ruby, JSON in Ruby is a string (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON), so it should look something like this.

```
item = "[{\"name\":\"Name 1\",\"value\":\"Value 1\"},{\"name\":\"Name 2\",\"value\":\"Value 2\"}]"
```

And because it is handled like a string, you need to parse it before you can manipulate the data, so you're code is almost correct, I just don't know why you first make your `item` a json and then parse it from JSON immediately.

```
data = JSON.parse(item)
p data.collect { |item| item['value'] }
```